# How to fix hover that effects an element in a container

Tags: html, css

I need to **scale** an image when I hover button/block that contains it but It doesn't work.

If I hover only image it scales perfectly but when I try to hover block it doesn't **affect** image.

So it will be like: hover button - image animation plays.

I expect that hovering block/button will affect image

```css
.cont {}

.btn-1 {
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f790b0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: none;
}

.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f58;
  position: absolute;
}

img {
  z-index: 4;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: 0.7s;
}

.btn-1:hover~img {
  transform: scale(1.2, 0.5);
}

span {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:400,700&display=swap&subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="cont">
  <div class="block">

    <div class="square"><img src="https://sandtonchronicle.co.za/wp-content/uploads/sites/33/2015/01/Facebook-logo-thum_621307002-423x317.jpg"></div>
    <button class="btn-1">
                Избранное
            </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet

Answer (score 1):

First you have to move the button and the square. Because with css, the previous element cannot be selected. Then the css should be like this. `.btn-1:hover~.square img` Then I took the picture before using `row-reverse`.

```css
.btn-1 {
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f790b0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: none;
}

.block {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f58;
}

img {
  z-index: 4;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: 0.7s;
}

.btn-1:hover~.square img {
  transform: scale(1.2, 0.5);
}

span {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="block">
    <button class="btn-1">
        Button
     </button>
    <div class="square"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use sibling selector, the element has to be after the hovered element, not before. After tweaking your code a little bit,
**HTML**

```
<div class="cont">
        <div class="block">
            <button class="btn-1">
                Избранное
            </button>
          <div class="square">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn-1 {
    font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #f790b0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border: none;
}

.square {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #f58;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

div.block{
  position: relative;
}

img {
    z-index: 4;
    position: absolute;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: 0.7s;

}

.btn-1:hover ~ div img{

  transform: scale(1.2, 0.5);

}

span {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/ashfaq_haq/pen/YzzQJBd